# "TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined" when running heroku app locally

Tags: angularjs, node.js, git, heroku

I followed this tutorial [here](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/mean-apps-restful-api), instead of only hosting the code on herokus git I hosted it on git. It works on heroku the app itself but when I pull it and run it locally using **node server.js** and It gives me the error below.

1. I've updated node
2. Run it using **heroku local** and **heroku local web**, same thing...
3. Making the app again from fresh.

I suspect its something to do with the mlab connection not getting through. Anyways any help greatly appreciated.

> C:\College\WebProg4\foodonline>node server.js
>       url.js:88
>           throw new TypeError('Parameter "url" must be a string, not ' + typeof url);
>           ^
>
> TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined
>           at Url.parse (url.js:88:11)
>           at Object.urlParse [as parse] (url.js:82:5)
>           at module.exports (C:\College\WebProg4\foodonline\node_modules\mongodb\lib\url_parser.js:15:23)
>           at connect (C:\College\WebProg4\foodonline\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:403:16)
>           at Function.MongoClient.connect (C:\College\WebProg4\foodonline\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:227:3)
>           at Object. (C:\College\WebProg4\foodonline\server.js:19:21)
>           at Module._compile (module.js:570:32)
>           at Object.Module._extensions..js (module.js:579:10)
>           at Module.load (module.js:487:32)
>           at tryModuleLoad (module.js:446:12)

**Server.JS**

```
var express = require("express");
var bodyParser = require("body-parser");
var mongodb = require("mongodb");
var ObjectID = mongodb.ObjectID;

var CONTACTS_COLLECTION = "contacts";

var app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());

// Create link to Angular build directory
var distDir = __dirname + "/dist/";
app.use(express.static(distDir));

// Create a database variable outside of the database connection callback to reuse the connection pool in your app.
var db;

// Connect to the database before starting the application server.
mongodb.MongoClient.connect(process.env.MONGODB_URI, function (err, database) {
  if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    process.exit(1);
  }

  // Save database object from the callback for reuse.
  db = database;
  console.log("Database connection ready");

  // Initialize the app.
  var server = app.listen(process.env.PORT || 8080, function () {
    var port = server.address().port;
    console.log("App now running on port", port);
  });
});
```

Comment: no need to start over the stack trace reports `server.js` line `19:21` where the error occurs , probably a variable that has no value ..`undefined`..try posting some code from `server.js`

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix yeah man, I added it there.

Comment: `process.env.MONGODB_URI` is not set or is invalid, take a look at the environmental variables.

Comment: @Mr.Phoenix yeah you were right, I change the process.env.MONGODB_URI to the correct url. Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`TypeError: Parameter "url" must be a string, not undefined`

reading from the stack trace

```
`at Function.MongoClient.connect(...\node_modules\mongodb\lib\mongo_client.js:227:3)
at Object.<anonymous> (......\server.js:19:21)`
```

`process.env.MONGODB_URI` is not defined or invalid.

you can add simple check before attempting to start your server about all the required parameters that might be undefined or invalid. Take a look https://blog.risingstack.com/10-best-practices-for-writing-node-js-rest-apis/ about the way configuration is handled.